# Force user to select option in dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

On starting the application for the first time I wanted to prompt the user (by dialog) to select their city, which would then consequently save their preference and load the proper data into the listview. However, I've noticed that a dialog can be closed by the back button, or pushing anywhere outside of the dialog box, which then triggers a null value for the database.

Is there anyway I can force the dialog box to stay open until the user has selected an option?

I've already implemented `.setCancelable(false)` and this does not seem to work. My code is below, **DialogSetup** being the inner class that I'm working with.

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private Cursor lines;
private MetroSleepDb db;
private ListAdapter adapter;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "METROSLEEP_PREFS";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    chooseCityDialog();




}




public void setAdapters() {

    db = new MetroSleepDb(this);
    lines = db.getLines(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread
    //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            lines, 
            new String[] {"line_id"}, 
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);


    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(onAnswerClicked);

}


public String getItem(int pos) {

    Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(pos);
    String value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("line_id"));
    return value;
}

private OnItemClickListener onAnswerClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        String line_value = getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseStations.class);
        intent.putExtra("line", line_value);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem  item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void chooseCityDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogSetup();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "citypref");
}

public static final class DialogSetup extends DialogFragment {
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.prompt_choose_city)
               .setCancelable(false) 
               .setItems(R.array.Cities, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       //
               }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Could you use that null value trigger as a way to start the dialog again to get an answer?

Comment: I could check to see if no value was selected and re-trigger the dialog. That is indeed a solution, thanks.

Comment: You also could use an `onDismissListener` to not dismiss if there is no value, I believe. Althoug, I don't know why `setCancelable(false)` isn't working. I haven't used a `DialogFragment` but works fine in other `Dialogs`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aha! You have to call [`setCancelable(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setCancelable(boolean)) on the `DialogFragment`, not the `AlertDialog.builder`. See this question: [AlertDialog's setCancelable(false) method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906269/alertdialogs-setcancelablefalse-method-not-working).

The documentation for `DialogFragment.setCancelable(boolean cancelable)` states:

> Control whether the shown Dialog is cancelable. Use this instead of directly calling Dialog.setCancelable(boolean), because DialogFragment needs to change its behavior based on this.

You just need to add 1 line of code:

```
public void chooseCityDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogSetup();
    newFragment.setCancelable(false);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "citypref");
}
```

Also, it would be a nice safety check to have a default city to fall back to, if somehow the city returned from the `Dialog` is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use an `AlertDialog` instead of `DialogFragment` for this.

```
    AlertDialog dlgBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dlgBuilder.setMessage("Title");
    dlgBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    okCalledMethodInactivity();
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Exit app", new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dlg = dlgBuilder.create();
    dlg.show();
```

Comment: Disagree, Google recommends you use `DialogFragment`s - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Comment: It is a bit confusing because the AlertDialog indeed lets you use 
`alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` and `alertDialog.setCancelable(false);` but I cannot seem to get a ListView inside a alertDialog without using the builder, which returns: 


**The method setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder**

Comment: Probably you need to use [setMultiChoiceItems](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence[], boolean[], android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)). I see the method setCanceledOnTouchOutside in the DialogInterface. So you need to first build the alert dialog and then use that method.

Comment: @markbratanov look at my answer, you need to call `setCancelable(false)` on the `DialogFragment`, since it is handling the behavior of the `AlertDialog`.

Comment: @StevenByle : Check this.  http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#alerts . Alert dialog still does the job. DialogFragment feels like a neat solution but IMO it is a overkill for such a small task.

Comment: @500865 `AlertDialog` is by no means dead. but by using `DialogFragment`, you get the state management of the `Dialog` provided by the `Fragment`, rather than having the track the state of your `AlertDialog` from within your parent `Activity` or `Fragment`. In reality, `DialogFragment` is just a wrapper for `AlertDialog`. I believe those docs are old, and have not been updated. By using `DialogFragment`, the OP has a more robust solution IMO, and I use them as well in all of my apps.

Comment: I agree that `DialogFragment` has its own benefits and regular Dialog Widgets (AlertDialog, ProgressDialog etc.,) its own. I don't think google would recommend using DialogFragment for every little dialogs you create. The choice depends on the problem you are trying to solve using the dialog box.

Answer (score -4):

Disable the back button by

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Comment: Then the user can never use the back button in this `Activity`...not a good idea

Comment: Agreed, this is an amateur hack, not a solution.