# AlertDialog dismissed when back pressed

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am using alert dialog with following properties.The problem is the dialog is dismiissed when i click back button or touch outside the dialog i don't want that.How can i solve this because setCancelable is not helping.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.check_internet);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: are you extending DialogFragment?

Comment: yes i am extending dialog fragment

Comment: Try this - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906269/alertdialogs-setcancelablefalse-method-not-working

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you are extending a `DialogFragment` you need to call

```
setCancelable(false);
```

inside its `onCreate`

only `setCancelable(false);`

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); // this activity context
builder.setMessage(R.string.check_internet);
AlertDialog alertDialog =builder.create();
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Try to put an activity there, which is in the bottom of stack(not the top)

Answer (score 0):

*This is the **default** behavior for all the **Android** devices, think twice before changing that because user **expects** it when he presses the **back** button*.

However you can change that behavior by **overriding** `OnBackPressed()` method of the `Dialog/DialogFragment` class. Don't call `super.OnBackPressed()` inside the overridden function however that **may leak memory** so be **careful**..

Comment: onBackPressed is not available in the class that extends DialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void showAlert1(){
     MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.check_internet); 
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();              
                }
            });
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

No that is the default behaviour of the alert dialog see this link [dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog)

Comment: One note about that comment. You can implement a onDismiss, however it seems to require API 17 as a min.